# How to nest resource in Laravel

Tags: laravel, resources

I have this 2 routes in my routes.php file

```
$router->resource('user','UserController');
$router->resource('usertype','UserTypeController');
```

but what i actualy want is to get the users and join the usertype with it
example
user table:
id name usertype_id
1  admin  2
2  john   1

usertype table:
id name
1  normal
2  admin

i want to get :
1 'john' 'normal'
2 'admin' 'admin'

i have tried this:

```
public function __construct(User $user)
    {

        $this->user = $user->with('usertype');

    }
```

This doesnt work good. it uses the user.id to set relations
so the query it will make is

```
select * from user_types where user_types.id = users.id
```

it should be

```
select * from user_types where user_types.id = users.user_type_id
```

And the seccond problem is that it does a query for every user,
explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swhWRMkpVsg

Comment: title and question doesn't match.... and post codes for the 2nd problem, not a video.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the sollution:
in the user controller:

```
public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user->with('usertype')->with('company');
    }
```

and in the user model:

```
public function usertype(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\UserType','user_type_id','id');
}

public function company(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company','company_id','id');
}
```